# Is it possible to use a ternary operator inside another ternary operator?

Tags: python-2.7, syntax, ternary-operator

So firstly, I tagged python 2.7 because the syntax may be different in 3.5

I used to do C# before python, and I discovered I were able to use ternary operators inside one another.

I'm curious if is is possible also in python since they are not in the same order.

C#
`condition ? output_true : output_false`

python
`output_true if condition else output_false`

Another way of asking my question would be:

How could I make a ternary operator that achieves the same as

```
if a:
    x = "a"
elif b:
    x = "b"
else c:
    x = "c"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear what you want to do if `a`, `b` and `c`  are `False`. But certainly, we can nest ternary operators:

```
x = "a" if a else ("b" if b else ("c" if c else None))
```

... But it's not a good idea to use the ternary operator if you have more than one condition, it'll be hard to read; stick to if/elif/else for those cases.

Comment: My apologies for the bad example code, I accidentally submitted a draft. But this answers my question perfectly. 

But duly noted, I will only ever use them if it makes the code easier to read. In most cases it wont, but sometimes it could. Thank you!